# Can not call Spring controller when use ajax

Tags: ajax, spring, url, model-view-controller, controller

I have a problem when use ajax with Spring

I want filter list result when I select region from select box or enter store name on screen so my idea is use Ajax to resolve this. But Ajax can not call to specific controller what is in url attribute of $.ajax

Below is my files:

1. JSP :

CSS id for  is appliedStoreSearch

```
<form:form modelAttribute="appliedStoreInput" id="appliedStoreSearch">

    <form:select path="regionId" cssClass="form-control">
        <form:option value="" label="Toàn quốc"></form:option>
        <form:options items="${listRegions}" />
    </form:select>

    <input type="email" class="form-control"placeholder="Tìm kiếm cửa hàng" name="storeNameInp" />
    <div class="input-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </div>

</form:form>
```

2. Ajax

   ```
   $(document).on('change','#appliedStoreSearch',function(e){
    var input = $("#appliedStoreSearch").serialize();
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       url:"/promotions_controller/search_applied_store_ajax",
       method:"POST",
       contentType : "application/json;",
       dataType:"json",
       data:input,
       success: function(data){
       }
   });
   e.preventDefault();
   });
   ```
3. Controller :

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value="/search_applied_store_ajax",method=RequestMethod.POST,produces="application/json" )
   public @ResponseBody List<AppliedStoreDto> searchAppliedStoreAjax( @ModelAttribute("appliedStoreInput")AppliedStoreInputDto appliedStoreinput){

       System.out.println("in ra 1 so thu gi go");

       List<AppliedStoreDto> listAppliedStore = null;

       appliedStoreinput.setCompanyId(7);

       try {

        // get list applied store
        listAppliedStore = promotionLogic.findAllAppliedStore(appliedStoreinput);

       } catch (Exception e) {

        logger.error(e.getMessage());

       }

     return listAppliedStore;
   }
   ```

I have debugged Javascript then I retrieved data from form but Spring controller (/promotions_controller/search_applied_store_ajax) still  can not be called by Ajax. There is not any things what is showed in console

Please help me, tks all!!!!

Comment: akuma8, Could you help me?

Comment: Could you add your controller mapping? Here you added only the handler method. Also chack if the request is really sent.

Answer (score 0):

Given your ajax call has contentType of "application/json;" I would look at adding consumes = "application/json" to your RequestMapping and swapping ModelAttribute for RequestBody

Answer (score 0):

Sean's answer is basically correct. Just adding the exact details. Function declaration should look like something like following

```
@RequestMapping(value="/search_applied_store_ajax",method=RequestMethod.POST,produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, consumes = {
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE} )
```

public @ResponseBody List searchAppliedStoreAjax( @RequestBody AppliedStoreInputDto appliedStoreinput){